# Sending a windows form value to a wpf control to update a property located in the wpf control.

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, interop

I have a hybrid application that I need to update a WPF control whenever an event is fired in the windows form.

I have a button click that will change the property of a string value, and depending on the string value, the WPF control should either draw a line or a rectangle. So when the user clicks either line or rectangle, how I transmit that to the WPF control?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose You have A WPF UserControl named WPFUC. And and an ElementHost named elementHost1. And elementHost contains WPFUC. And the WPFUC has a public property named String Parameter. Then:

```
WPFUC userControl = (WPFUC)elementHost1.Child;
userControl.Parameter = "line"; //To draw line
or
userControl.Parameter = "rectangle"; //To draw rectangle
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: THANK YOU! That was incredibly simple, yet so elegant! I am so excited to be able to continue my program now. Much appreciated!